# Not able to put file on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, talend, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am having CDH virtual box running on my windows 10. I am running simple talend job, which has only component to put file on HDFS (tHDFSPut) from windows to HDFS which is located in virtual box. But when I run the job the file is created on HDFS but it is empty.

I am getting following error,

`org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/cloudera/test/Input.xml could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1716)`

I checked, namenode is healthy and it is having sufficient disk space available, also I can able to access it outside the virtual box using `localhost:50070`

Need help!

Comment: Restart all services and try again

Comment: I tried restarting namenode,secondarynamenode and datanode. But problem still persist.

Comment: `1 node(s) are excluded in this operation` means there is an error with the namenode communicating to the datanode. Cloudera Manager should be saying something is unhealthy

Comment: When I try to put file within the virtual box using '-put' command, it works. So I don't think that is the problem.